# Calculating area of a non-self-intersecting polygon with n vertices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists, area

I want to find the area of a non-self intersecting polygon using a 2d list of x,y points. For example given the list [(0, 0), (4, 0), (2, 2), (4, 4), (0, 4), (2, 2)] I want to find the area. Using the formula [image]

I know it is possible but I have a lot of difficulty with comparing 2 different points in lists. Help with how to iterate through the list properly would be great

EDIT: I want to make it work for a polygon with any number of sides (so the list can be any size that would create a polygon

Comment: If aa is the list, just use print statements to find the list elements, like `aa[0,0])` or their lenghts `len(aa)` , .  Likely your y (i+1) will be something like `aa[i+1,1]`, whereas x(i) would be `aa[i,0]`.  Play with that and show it. You can also use numpy to convert the list of tuples you have into numpy arrays (like an = np.array(aa)). With transpose you could then make yourself the x and y vectors for easier readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand how to iterate through lists,tuples use some print statements first:

```
a=[(0, 0), (4, 0), (2, 2), (4, 4), (0, 4), (2, 2)]   

print(type(a))
print(type(a[0]))

print(a[1])  # 2nd tuple

print(a[1][0])  # first element of 2nd tuple all positions in python lists,tuples etc are zero based)
print(a[-1][0])  # first element of last tuple

n=len(a)
print(n)
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
(4, 0)
4
2
6
```

Then your actual problem becomes easy to write:

```
sum=0
for i in range(n-1 ):
    sum+= a[i][0]*a[i+1][1]- a[i+1][0]*a[i][1]

print(sum/2)
```

output:

```
8.0
```

This is not superfast and pretty. If you want the latter, you'd use `numpy` arrays. But it should give you insight in how to understand your data and implement computations that work on lists or tuples.

Comment: Shouldn't I use a different variable name for the added numbers as sum is already predefined?

Comment: `sum=0` just initializes the variable. Then you keep adding to it during the loop.  If you don't do that you might have another variable `sum` further up and you'd keep adding to that one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is an exercise where you are trying to specifically use that formula, but if you're just interested in getting the area you can try Python's [shapely module](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html).

```
from shapely import geometry

pts =  [(0, 0), (4, 0), (2, 2), (4, 4), (0, 4), (2, 2)] 

polygon = geometry.Polygon(pts)
print (polygon.area)  # 8.0
```

Comment: I am specifically trying to use that formula sadly, thank you for the other solution though!